# Skip to next record in a pl sql Cursor with Bulk Collect

Tags: plsql, cursor, bulk-collect

Please analyze the below code snippet and suggest a way to skip to the next record in the cursor.

BEGIN

```
OPEN cs_migrate_drop_ntd_object_status;

LOOP

    FETCH cs_migrate_drop_ntd_object_status BULK COLLECT INTO r_current_loc_equip LIMIT 200;

    FOR i IN 1..r_current_loc_equip.COUNT
    LOOP
        IF ( r_current_loc_equip(i).status = 'YES' ) THEN
            **-- Here I want to skip to next record fetched by the bulk collect cursor**
        ELSE
            Do something else;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [CONTINUE](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e17126/continue_statement.htm#LNPLS01360):

```
FOR i IN 1..r_current_loc_equip.COUNT
LOOP
    IF ( r_current_loc_equip(i).status = 'YES' ) THEN
        CONTINUE;
    ELSE...
```

You could also use it like this:

```
FOR i IN 1..r_current_loc_equip.COUNT
LOOP
    CONTINUE WHEN r_current_loc_equip(i).status = 'YES';
    Do something else;
```

(Better still, if you don't want to process rows where status='YES', don't select them in the cursor in the first place.)